# Programmatically get current multi-site instance name

Tags: 8, multi-sites

Let's say I have the following multi-site setup:

```
$sites['hello-world-a.com']       = 'a';
$sites['stage.hello-world-a.com'] = 'a';
$sites['dev.hello-world-a.com']   = 'a';
$sites['hello-world-a.localhost'] = 'a';

$sites['hello-world-b.com']       = 'b';
$sites['stage.hello-world-b.com'] = 'b';
$sites['dev.hello-world-b.com']   = 'b';
$sites['hello-world-b.localhost'] = 'b';
```

Works fine. Both share the same theme and more or less the same features. Now let's say I have a very simple preprocess function that adds a CSS class to the body:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';

}
```

#### How can I now add the multi-site instance's name as body class dynamically?

- Without going through all possible domain names and string comparison?
- Also possibly without working with the human readable site name, which may change?
- Maybe with [cache contexts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts)?
- Or UUID?

---

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'foo';

  // Basically along the following pattern.
  if ( @@@ SITE A @@@ ) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = @@@ SITE A @@@;
  }

}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks like you'll have to implement your own logic similar to `DrupalKernel::findSitePath`, which includes sites/sites.php, breaks down the current host into an appropriate string, and checks the `$sites` array for a matching key. If your requirements can be satisfied by getting the site folder, e.g. "sites/a" for your first group of sites, then you can just call the static `DrupalKernel::findSitePath` directly with the current request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to @Clive for telling me about [`DrupalKernel::findSitePath`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AfindSitePath/8.5.x) which takes the current [`$request`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AcreateFromGlobals/8.5.x) to then return the path of the matching multi-site directory.

And thanks to @4k4 for the tip that there's also a [service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services) for that. But this service got [deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/3080612) in Drupal 9 and will have been removed from Drupal 10, so back to to `DrupalKernel::findSitePath`. This works in Drupal 8, 9 and 10:

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  
  // This will get you a string for example: 'sites/default'.
  $site_path = \Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::findSitePath(\Drupal::request());

  // Explode it to only get the 'default' part in the next step.
  $site_path = explode('/', $site_path);
  $site_name = $site_path[1];

  // Add current site name as CSS class to the body.
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'site-' . \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($site_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quicker alternative is to add a `$settings['current_multisite']` with the desired value on each `setting.php` then use it for checkings:

```php
<?php
# settings.php of "bar" site
$settings['current_multisite'] = 'foo';

# settings.php of "bar" site
$settings['current_multisite'] = 'bar';
```

Then you can access it anywhere:

```php
<?php
// Fallbacks to "null" if some multisite did not specified "current_multisite" 
$multisite = Settings::get('current_multisite');
```