# Show currently active multisite

Tags: 8

Is there a way to see which [multisite configuration](https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal) is currently active in the drupal admin web interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "currently active"?

Comment: The one whose settings.php is used when accessing the web interface.

Comment: There's no UI for it but you can create your own using the logic here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257325/programmatically-get-current-multi-site-instance-name